# Delayed Job: is there a way to make sure that only one job is processed at a time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a long-running task that I want to run using Delayed Job. Is there a way to guarantee that if multiple tasks of the same type are queued at the same time then they will be processed sequentially?

Comment: How many DJ worker processes do you have? that's important. Also, is it just a simple delayed method, or is it a worker object?

Comment: you could implement a singleton to manage the queued jobs perhaps? probably you could pass it a function and instance variable to represent a queued job? then when a job finished it could make a call to the singleton which would let it know that it was time to call send_later on the next queued job?...

Comment: @tompave: I have 4 worker processes. Currently it is a delayed method, but I can refactor it to be an object if needed.